# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.io' has no attribute 'experimental'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to call a function from tensorflow to decode a tiff image, while i am running the notebook on kaggle notebooks and in this line:

```
img = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(img, channels=1)
```

It gives me the error:

> AttributeError: in user code:
>
> ```
> <ipython-input-5-d30698f56813>:11 load  *
>     img = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(img, channels=1)
>
> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.io' has no attribute 'experimental'
> ```

I'm currently importing tensorflow.io like this:

```
import tensorflow.io as tfio
```

And my current version of: `print(f"Tensorflow ver. {tf.__version__}")` is

> Tensorflow ver. 2.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tensorflow I/O does not come with Tensorflow, and it must be installed separately via `pip`; from the [repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/io#tensorflow-io) (emphasis mine):

> TensorFlow I/O is a collection of file systems and file formats that are **not** available in TensorFlow's built-in support.

Moreover, it is not imported like that.

What you should do is install it via `pip`:

```
!pip install tensorflow-io
```

and verify that you get the latest version v0.15.0, as it is currently the only one compatible with TF 2.3 ([source](https://github.com/tensorflow/io#tensorflow-version-compatibility)):

```
import tensorflow_io as tfio
tfio.__version__
# 0.15.0
```

Notice the different import - `tensorflow_io`, **not** `tensorflow.io`; this is demonstrated also in the simple usage examples in [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/io#tensorflow-io).

Comment: Yep. I got error "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'io'" at "tensorboard\summary\writer\event_file_writer.py", line 72, in \_\_init\_\_
    tf.io.gfile.makedirs(logdir)". The installation of tensorflow-io fixed the error. Thanks!